# How to compare all items in a list with an integer without using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a couple of lists which vary in length, and I would like to compare each of their items with an integer, and if any one of the items is above said integer, it breaks the for loop that it is in.

```
for list in listoflists:
    if {anyiteminlist} > 70:
        continue    #as in skip to next list

    {rest of code here}
```

Basically, I need to say: "If anything in this list is above 70, continue the loop with the next list"

Comment: What is the reason not to use a nested for loop? Any internal method that list has will still use an O(n) search to find out if any element is greater than some number (70). If you really need to avoid a nested O(n) search, use a different/custom data structure.

Comment: Not that it matters, but in your pseudocode you write "if {anyiteminlist} > 70: continue", but you write "if anything in this list is *below* 70, continue the loop with the next list".  Am I misreading, or are those almost opposites?

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.
No, it's not homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd probably do it using the generator expression, but since no one else has suggested this yet, and it doesn't have an (explicit) nested loop:

```
>>> lol = [[1,2,3],[4,40],[10,20,30]]
>>> 
>>> for l in lol:
...     if max(l) > 30:
...         continue
...     print l
... 
[1, 2, 3]
[10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: `max` will not short-circuit, but `any` will - that is, the first element of the list greater than the threshold value will cause `any` to evaluate to True. `max` will look at every value to find the maximum value, even if the first element of the list exceeds the threshold and the rest don't really need to be looked at.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: yep.  The only possible advantage to computing the max is that it avoids an explicit loop, and the only reason I can think of to do that is if that's what a question asked for.. (and I don't mean this question here on SO.)

Comment: I suspect that the "no for loop" condition may have been due to some question over how to continue the outer loop from inside the inner loop.  A "continue" in the inner loop would just continue the inner loop, not the outer loop.

Answer (score 23):

Don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin `list()`. There is a builtin function called [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) which is useful here

```
if any(x>70 for x in the_list):
```

The part inbetween the `(` and `)` is called a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function [any](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) like this:

```
for list in listoflists:
    if any(x < 70 for x in list):
        continue
```

The `any` function does short-circuit evaluation, so it will return `True` as soon as an integer in the list is found that meets the condition.

Also, you should not use the variable `list`, since [it is a built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list).

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it to this :D

```
for good_list in filter(lambda x: max(x)<=70, listoflists):
   # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 2.5 or greater, you can use the any() function with list comprehensions.

```
for list in listoflists:
  if any([i > 70 for i in list]):
    continue
```

Comment: You don't need or want the list-comp inside the any: it prevents short-circuiting.

Comment: `for i in list` still looks like a for loop to me.

Comment: @Alan - its a generator expression that uses `for` to define the values to be generated. In this form, it is a for loop that is executed in fast C code, not in slow Python code.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: That's interesting. I did not know that. I was merely pointing out that the original question (oddly) stated no nested for loop. Regardless, even if it's implemented faster, or executed on faster hardware, at some point n^2 will always be slower than Nlog(n)

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin `any` is the clearest way. Alternatively you can nest a for loop and break out of it (one of the few uses of for-else construct).

```
for lst in listoflists:
    for i in lst:
        if i > 70:
            break
    else:
        # rest of your code
        pass
```