# Python, RGB color comparisons

Tags: python, opencv

I have a pixel from an OpenCV image with the RGB format in [r,g,b]. I would like to run a test so that if i find a color darker than [150,150,150] i stop a for loop.

This is what I have so far:

```
def test():
    for l in range(y, y+h):
        for d in range(x, x+w):
            print(image[l,d][0])
            if image[l,d] <= [150,150,150]:
                return;
            image[l,d] = [0,0,0]
```

Doesn't work though. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it is. print(image[l,d]) = [  0 255   0]

Comment: `if all(item <= 150 for item in image[l, d]):`. Does this work?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here are some related topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052857/comparing-two-lists-using-the-greater-than-or-less-than-operator and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254897/how-to-compare-all-items-in-a-list-with-an-integer-without-using-for-loop

Comment: The pixel value is a numpy array. Hence something like `if np.all(image[l,d] <= [150,150,150]): ...` will do.

Answer (score 3):

Since OpenCV images in Python are represented as numpy arrays, each pixel value will also be a numpy array. That means that the comparison operation will be vectorized, and return an array of boolean values, for example

```
>>> image[l,d] <= [150,150,150]
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Now, you want to check that the condition is satisfied for all the item pairs. That's where [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) comes into play.

```
>>> np.all(image[l,d] <= [150,150,150])
True
```

In fact, numpy arrays have a member method `all()`, which does the same thing.

```
>>> (image[l,d] <= [150,150,150]).all()
True
```