# How to compare values in a list with a specific integer value?

Tags: python

I have a function which returns say either [1], [1,2],[1,2,3] or [1,2,3,4].  I want to compare the values inside the list with some value( say 0.2).

Before this, I had just an integer value coming from my function not a list of values to compare with 0.2.`

```
# this function gives a list as mentioned previously
iou_value = oneObject.intersection_over_union(image,humanPos,belongings_bb)     

if iou_value is not None and iou_value > 0.2:
```

How should I write the if condition in such a scenario to compare list values with 0.2?

Thanks

Comment: @Sociopath I just do not know how to write it in an if condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare all items in a list with an integer without using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254897/how-to-compare-all-items-in-a-list-with-an-integer-without-using-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any()`

**Ex:**

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

if any(iou_value > 0.2 for iou_value in a):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends what exactly you want, but most likely list comprehension will help you:

```
compared_list = [1 for elem in iou_value if elem > 0.2 else 0]
```

Will give you 1 and 0 at corresponding indices

Edit: if you want to separate the elements based on the comparison:

```
geq = [elem for elem in iou_value if elem >= 0.2]
less = [elem for elem in iou_value if elem < 0.2]
```

Edit 2: if you want a simple loop with if-conditions:

```
for elem in iou_value:
    if elem >= 0.2:
        #do what you want if geq
    else:
        #do what you want if less
```

Comment: `[bool(elem > 0.2) for elem in iou_value]` is a compact way of writing it, and you can use `filter()` to separate the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the list to compare each value, like this:

```
if iou_value is not None:
  for v in iou_value:
    if v > 0.2:
      print(f'{v} is greater than 0.2')
```

You may want to adjust your method so that instead of returning `None`, it returns an empty list `[]`, this way you can also delete the `if io_value is not None` check.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` condition with  would do this:

```
In [2090]: l = [1,2,3,4]

In [2091]: val = 0.2

In [2093]: for i in l:
      ...:     if i > val:
      ...:         print('{} is greater than {}'.format(i,val))
      ...:         
1 is greater than 0.2
2 is greater than 0.2
3 is greater than 0.2
4 is greater than 0.2
```

OR use `list comprehensions`:

```
In [2096]: ['yes' for i in l if i > val]
Out[2096]: ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes']
```